# How can I make python save a file in a different location?

Tags: python

My python project has 2 files. I made a folder called `files` so when the user writes something in the text editor, it saves it into that folder, then when the user opens the textviewer, they type that file name and looks for it in the `files` directory. How would I be able to do this?

Code for text editor:

```
def edit():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print ("EDIT")
    print ("-------------")
    print ("Note: Naming this current document the same as a different document will replace the other document with this one.")
    filename = input("Plese enter a file name.")
    file = open(filename, "w")
    print ("FILE: " +filename+".")
    lines = get_lines()
    file.write('\n'.join(lines))

def get_lines():
   print("Enter 'stop' to end.")
   lines = []
   line = input()
   while line != 'stop':
      lines.append(line)
      line = input()
   return lines
```

Text Viewer Code:

```
def textviewer():
   os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
   print ("Text Viewer.")
   file_name = input("Enter a text file to view: ")
   file = open(file_name, "r")
   print ("Loading text...")
   time.sleep(0.5)
   os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
   print(file.read())
   edit_text = input("Would you like to edit it? (y for yes, n for no)")
   if edit_text == "y":
      file = open(file_name, "w")
      print ("You are now in edit mode.")
      lines = get_lines
      file.write('\n'.join(lines))
      time.sleep(2)
   if edit_text == "n":
      print ("Press enter to exit")
      input()
```

Comment: You could use `os.path.join` to add the path to your `files` folder to the input file name.

Comment: How and where would I use it? I've never used `os` before, only when using clear screen, but thats it.

Comment: I'm sorry but you should really start by looking up the documentation on https://python.org.

Comment: Ok, I looked up the documentation, did `os.path.join(/media/GENERAL/Projects/files)`, syntax error. Added quotation marks, `os.path.join("/media/GENERAL/Projects/files")` worked, but didn't save in `files` directory. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I have no idea because you're not showing anything.

Comment: Folders exist relative to something. By default its the directory that the user happens to be in when the program is run. So, where in the file system do you want `files` to be? If its in the user home directory, and the file you want is in a variable called `filename`, then `os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'files', filename)` would work.

Comment: Try `os.path.join("/media/GENERAL/Projects/files", file_name)`

Comment: `os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'files', filename)` and `os.path.join("/media/GENERAL/Projects/files", file_name)` didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want `filename` to be considered relative to the current working directory, you should transform it into a more specific absolute path before passing it to `open`. Use `os.path.join` to combine a directory name and the file name together in a platform independent way:

```
directory = "/media/GENERAL/Projects/files"
filename = input("Plese enter a file name.")
file = open(os.path.join(directory, filename), "w")
```

Unrelated to this issue, but involving the same parts of the code, I'd suggest using `with` statements to handle your files (`with open(whatever) as file:`). See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for some more details.